# Express - can't serve static files in debug

Tags: node.js, express

I cannot serve static files in **debug** mode. I am using Passport authentication. Index.html is login page with form (POST to /login). In debug mode after successful authentication server redirect to /home but I cannot GET my css and javascript files.

Files are in /public directory.

```
/public
   /css
   /javascripts
   /images
   index.html
   home.html
/routes
```

in app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

in routes/index.js

```
/* GET Home Page */
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    var root = join(__dirname, '/..');
    root = join(root, '/public/');
    res.sendFile('home.html', { root: root});
});
/* Handle Login POST */
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash : true  
    }));
```

I am using VS Code. Here's launch.json.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/www",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "preLaunchTask": null,
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outDir": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5858,
        "address": "localhost",
        "restart": false,
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outDir": null,
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach to Process",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command.PickProcess}",
        "port": 5858,
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outDir": null
    }
]
```

}

Comment: How are you loading your .css and .js files?

Comment: In html file using <link> and <script> 


`<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>`

Comment: Where are materialize.min.js and materialize.min.css files stored?

Comment: Above comment, keeping in mind that you set app.use... to 'public'

Comment: materialize folder is in public. Everything works perfect until I start application in debug mode in VS Code. In '/' directory app load css, js files etc. Then I type credentials (user,password) and after successful authorization an app redirect from '/' to '/home'. In '/home' directory I can't load css,js files (but only in debug mode).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. For me it was that the working directory was not set correctly. Setting it to the folder containing my static root worked. In your case you might try:

```
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/www",
```